# ssh through authentication requiring proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, authentication

At work we have of course a company's-proxy. I need to ssh to some machines out of the company's network. The proxy, though, requires authentication.

Let's assume we have the following variables:

```
proxy_user="<username I need to authenticate at the proxy>"
proxy_pass="<password I need to authenticate at the proxy>"
proxy_serv="<hostname of the proxy>"
proxy_port=<port of the proxy>
ssh_user="<remote username I need to login on the ssh-machine>"
ssh_serv="<remote password I need to login on the ssh-machine>"
ssh_port=<ssh-port>
```

When setting the env-variable http_proxy and https_proxy as follows,
tools like wget work fine
(on the remote server, there is also a web_server installed):

```
$ export env http_proxy="http://$proxy_user:$proxy_pass@$proxy_serv:$proxy_port"

$ wget $ssh_serv
Connecting to <proxy_serv>... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

But with ssh it does not work:

```
$ ssh $ssh_user@$ssh_server:$ssh_port
ssh: Could not resolve hostname <ssh_server>:<ssh_port> Temporary failure in name resolution
```

After googl-ing a little, I found out, that ssh needs a "ProxyCommand". 
"nc" is not longer recommended here; "ssh -W" shall be used. 
But I couldn't find an example where authentication was needed. 
I tried so far:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p $proxy_user:$proxy_pass@$proxy_serv:$proxy_port'" $ssh_user@$ssh_serv:$ssh_port
```

I guess I'm missing something somewhere, but couldn't find a good hint
(neither in the manuals, nor on Google).

I hope that some of you guys might help me out.

Comment: This [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts) mentions a new `ProxyJump` option.

Comment: IMHO you need socks proxy, not http

Comment: @meuh: I have openssh_7.2 on my machine, which doesn't support -J option unfortunately

Comment: btw: I was able to connect to the remote server via FileZilla, through HTTP Proxy (used sftp protocol to my ssh-port).

Comment: (1) Your first code block indicates that `ssh_serv` is your password.  Your second code block suggests that you are passing that value as a command-line argument to `wget`.  Is that really what you mean?  (2) `export env abc="def"` creates a phantom exported variable called “`env`”.  You should say just `export abc="def"`.  (2b) There are obscure technical reasons why it might be better to say `abc="def"` and `export abc` as two separate commands (optionally, on the same line, *separated by a semicolon*), but the combined form is usually OK. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (3) [You should always quote all references to shell variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216 "Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells") (e.g., `"$ssh_user"`, `"$ssh_server"` and `"$ssh_port"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. For example, `ssh "$ssh_user@$ssh_server:$ssh_port"`. (You can quote them individually if you want, but that’s only rarely necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now after hours of googling I finally got it working for me with help of "corkscrew".
My ssh-server is running currently on Port 443 (haven't tried yet, whether it would be possible on 22 as well).

~/.ssh/config

```
Host <my.ssh.server>
    ProxyCommand corkscrew <my.companies.proxy> <proxy.port> %h %p ~/corkscrew-auth
```

~/.corkscrew-auth

```
<proxies.username>:<proxies.password>
```

Now I was able to connect to my server via:

```
ssh <remote.user>@<my.ssh.server> -p 443
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for a test - have you considered using `nc` anyway? When I would try to make proxy commands work, I was usually doing so at the config level: `/root/.ssh/config`

For example, the config would have the following:

```
Host ssh.example.com
    ProxyCommand ssh root@proxy.example.com nc %h %p
```

This is saying whenever you connect to ssh.example.com, it will use the ProxyCommand below. I suggest giving that a shot, if you absolutely can't use the netcat utility, I'm sure we can think of a workaround.

Comment: i already tried the nc approach, but haven't had an idea for the authentication either. %h %p only refer to host and port. ssh_config(5) didn't tell anything about user and password

Comment: This command work when you use jump server (again ssh) as proxy.

Comment: when i use the .ssh/config - approach, I get a name-resolution error, because he does not seem to understand, that he shall use the proxy for name resolution

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for this:

First install this Debian/Ubuntu/Mint package:

```
apt-get install connect-proxy
```

Export credentials if you are working behind proxy with authentication:

```
export HTTP_PROXY_USER=<user>
export HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD=<password>
```

Access ssh config file on `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and set remote host port:

```
Port 443
```

Set server alive interval to avoid connection loss:

```
ServerAliveInterval 20
```

Set ProxyCommand to use the connect recently installed package:

```
ProxyCommand connect -H <proxy>:<port> %h %p
```

Close ssh config file, then you are ready to execute ssh connection:

```
ssh -N -D localhost:1080 <remoteuser>@<remotehost>
```

Open Firefox, configure Network Settings to only use Socket 5 with:

Host: `localhost` Port: `1080`

Enable also `Proxy DNS when using SOCKS v5`.

Finally, in Firefox search tab, type the following:

```
about:config
```

Find `network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost` and set to `true`.

Now you are ready to connect behind proxy and use Firefox to explore behind created tunnel.

Comment: (1) Is it really necessary to put the password in the environment (in clear text)?  This is generally considered to be insecure.  (2) I assume that, when you say “*`<something>`*”, you mean it as a placeholder.  So what do you mean by `<proxy>`?  Do you mean proxy server hostname?  (3) What do you mean by “configure Connection settings to only use Socket 5 with host localhost (and) port 1080”? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.